# Is this a right approach to use Enum to persist it in database?

Tags: java, database, jpa, enums, one-to-many

So, I have a class(an entity) which has OneToMany relationship with an enum (another entity)

```
@Entity
class MyClass {
    @Id
    int id;

    @OneToMany
    List<MyEnumWrapper> myEnum;
}

public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2
    ;
}

@Entity
public class MyEnumWrapper {
    @Id
    private String value;

    public MyEnumWrapper(MyEnum value){
           this.value = value
    }

    public MyEnum getValue {
           return MyEnum.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

Does wrapping the enum just to make a different table for it in the database makes sense ?

EDIT: I get the problems with this design. But, my requirement is to have a separate table for the enum as it will get associated with many entities. So, is there a standard way to make table of just an Enum ?

Comment: No. Never. Read JPA docs

Comment: Do you mean many entities of _other_ classes? Or of the same class? I don't get the use case of an table that contains just the enums - as anything you could do with that could be done with the bare enum columns as well.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke Yes, many entities of other classes along with the instances of the same class.

Comment: Ok, again - what is this table for? There is no use to have a table "MyEnum" and an reference into that table in "myEnumColumn" - as that column could contain the ordinal from Java even without the extra table. Joins on this column are possible as well. If you want to have a table that contains ID _and_ name of the enum, than you should consider to drop the restriction of an enum and use a bare entity.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't make much sense. First because the association is probably not a OneToMany, but a ManyToMany: a given enum is probably contained in several instances of MyClass.

Second because, if that's really what you want, why would you use a String as the ID of the enum wrapper rather than using the enum itself?

Finally, unless you really want a table containing only the enum instances, you could simply use an element collection:

```
@Entity
class MyClass {
    @Id
    int id;

    @ElementCollection
    Set<MyEnum> myEnums = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jb. It's right that it's actually a ManyToMany relationship. But, still I  need to have a separate table for the Enum as it will be associated with other entities too. Any suggestion for that ?